# Variable value retention while recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have following pseudocode where I need to update the counter value if tree is an instance of binaryTree. If tree has more children I call the method recursively & increment the counter.

The issue is if I make the counter static (which I don't want to), counter values are fine but when I pass the variable as an input to the method (as mentioned below) I just get the value 1. What is wrong here?

```
//Pseudo code
public static int test(tree) {
    Integer count = 0;
    return testTreeRecCounts(tree, count);
}

private static Integer testTreeRecursiveCounts(tree, Integer count) {
    if (tree instanceof  binaryTree) {
        count++;
        for (Node node :tree.getChild())) {
            testTreeRecursiveCounts((tree)node, count);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: you should add result of `testTreeRecursiveCounts` method calls in `for` loop as well to get proper result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `Integer` is **immutable**, so the moment you do this `count++`, the `count` will point to different object.

The process is : count -> unboxing -> increase the value by 1 -> auto boxing (which created a new object).

That's why, only the first object with value 1 is return.

Also note that using `Integer` instead of its primitive `int` will slow down the performance as it needs to do autoboxing/unboxing continuously.

This problem can be fixed by doing something like this:

```
private static int testTreeRecursiveCounts(tree) {
    int count =0;
    if (tree instanceof  binaryTree) {
        count++;
        for (Node node :tree.getChild())) {
           count += testTreeRecursiveCounts((tree)node);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: won't this initialize count to 0 every time recursive call is made?

Comment: @AhmedFahad Because we keep adding the count for all its child (look inside the for loop) so the result will be the total of all its children plus one, this result will again be passed to its parent so its parent can update properly. This is call backtracking :)